# Understanding Local Storage & Cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form on my page with text boxes, radio buttons and drop down menus that ask questions about students. The options selected from these will later be used to make a div containing each student's content. My directions say to save the list to local storage. I'm confused on what exactly this means. I tried looking this up and cookies kept coming up. I thought these were 2 different things. I'm confused on the concept of local storage. I've searched this on Google and Stack and have read what ever I could find related to these topics. I think I need this explained in a simple way rather then reading a textbook definition or answers to questions people have asked about there code relating to cookies and local storage. Can someone explain these 2 topics? Are cookies and local storage the same things? I'm not sure if it's different for other languages but I'm using **Javascript**.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: In no way did I ask for a whole course. I am well aware Stack is not a place to give computer courses. Stack is a place to learn no matter your level of expertise, which is why the website allows anyone of any level to ask questions. I would just like clarification on 2 topics. I do not see anything wrong in asking for a more simple or visual representation of any topic to get clarification. @MisterJojo

Comment: Cookies and localStorage are both ways to persist information in the browser for longer than a page visit. They are not inherently part of JS, but different systems that you can access from JS, and not all such persisted information can always be accessed from JS. There is too much about cookies and localStorage to answer in an SO answer in a way that gives you competence in using these systems, and you'd be better served googling `tutorial localStorage` or `tutorial cookies javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` is an API that the browser provides to allow you to read and write data. You can kind of imagine it as a single large JavaScript object, storing data values under different keys. Using it is easy: `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` (for some key and value, e.g. `localStorage.setItem('test', 23)`) to write a value and `localStorage.getItem(key)` to read/access that value. Details and examples can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Cookies are accessed through the API `document.cookie`. `document.cookie` also uses pairs of keys and values (the cookies) to store data; however, the approach for reading and writing cookies is different. To create a new cookie, you enter `document.cookie = "key=value"` (for some key and value, e.g. `document.cookie = "test=23"`). To see all cookies, enter `document.cookie`, which will spit out all cookies as a string of keys and values, separated by semicolons (e.g. `"test=23; someOtherKey=59"`). Unfortunately, this makes reading cookie values a little trickier than with `localStorage`; the simplest way to get the value for a single key would be to use a Regular Expression, a specific pattern for matching text. More details and examples can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

In terms of how you use them, they're similar in that they both are used for storing data. However, cookies are mainly sent to the browser from the server along with the page; `localStorage`, in contrast, is only accessible to the JavaScript code in the browser.

Hope this helps!

[**EDIT**]

[See also](https://medium.com/swlh/cookies-vs-localstorage-whats-the-difference-d99f0eb09b44)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and localstorage are not the same things.

**Cookies**

Cookies are small files that contain information useful to a web site — such as password, preferences, browser, IP Address, date and time of visit, etc. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user’s previous activity. Cookies have a certain life span defined by their creators and it expires after the fixed time span.

**localStorage**

The localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. That means it won't clear until you remove it. In another way, localStorage has no expiration time.

Add data to localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Remove Item

```
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');
```

Remove all items

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Also, there is another thing called sessionStorage. Which is same as localStorage but data only stored until the browser session is closed.