Can I use cookies for a standard HTML file?
I tried to pass a cookie to remember the user's login details:
const expiresIn24Hours = new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = `uuid=${userId}; expires=${expiresIn24Hours}; path=/; `;
    document.cookie = `firstName=${firstName}; expires=${expiresIn24Hours}; path=/; `;

When I use an HTML file with this code and console.log the cookie, it shows nothing.
However, when I run it in Live Server for VS Code, the cookie displays properly:
uuid=[MyUUID]; firstName=[MyFirstName]

Can a cookie be implemented in a .html file?
Do you need to have a server for it?

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783824/understanding-local-storage-cookies-in-javascript

As I remember Cookie require 'HTTP' server.
The answer is YES, To use cookie you will need an HTTP server.
